# Having milliseconds in my timer in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, timer

I'm doing a stopwatch using a youtube tutorial. The problem is that I want milliseconds in my timer but the tutorial only shows how to get seconds and minutes. I would like to get the milliseconds displayed like the minutes and seconds, but I've got no idea how to do it.

How to get milliseconds using this code?

```
@implementation ViewController {

    bool start;
    NSTimeInterval time;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.display.text = @"0:00";
    start = false;
}

- (void) update {

    if ( start == false ) {
        return;
    }
    NSTimeInterval currentTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    NSTimeInterval elapsedTime = currentTime - time;

    int minutes = (int) (elapsedTime / 60.0);

    int seconds = (int) (elapsedTime = elapsedTime - (minutes * 60));

    self.display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u:%02u", minutes, seconds];

    [self performSelector:@selector(update) withObject:self afterDelay:0.1];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs, "NSTimeInterval is always specified in seconds; it yields sub-millisecond precision over a range of 10,000 years." So all you need to do is extract the milliseconds from your `elapsedTime` variable and then format your text again so that it includes milliseconds. It might looks something like this:

```
NSInteger time = (NSInteger)elapsedTime;
NSInteger milliseconds = (NSInteger)((elapsedTime % 1) * 1000);
NSInteger seconds = time % 60;
NSInteger minutes = (time / 60) % 60;
//if you wanted hours, you could do that as well
//NSInteger hours = (time / 3600);
self.display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: "%ld:%ld.%ld", (long)minutes, (long)seconds, (long)milliseconds];
```

Comment: You are welcome. Glad it helped. If this worked for you, could you accept this as the answer when you get a chance? (green check mark). Thanks.